# Как аттачить скриншот на КАЖДОМ шагу теста (python, pytest, allure)

Tags: python, pytest, screenshots, allure

Всем доброго времени суток

Наш тестовый фреймворк содержит классы страниц с методами, задекорированными с помощью allure.step:

```
@step('I login to application by user {user_name}')
def login(self, user_name: str) -> None:
    ....
```

Когда встал вопрос с возможностью получения в репорте скриншотов на каждый шаг, мы поняли что, конечно, можем делать скриншот в конце каждого метода-шага, что не является красивым решением.
Тогда мы решили попробовать заменить `allure.step` собственным декоратором на его основе.

```
def step(step_title):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            # with allure.step(step_title):
            _self = args[0]
            allure.step(step_title)(func(*args, **kwargs))
            if get_config().reporting.screen_each_step:
                allure.attach(_self.driver.get_screenshot_as_png(), "step screenshot", allure.attachment_type.PNG)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Но при использовании `allure.step()()` скриншоты аттачатся не в тело шагов, а в тело самих кейсов.
При использовании `with allure.step()` скриншоты аттачатся в тело степа, как и задумывалось. Но есть ряд других проблем: подстановка аргументов метода в title шага не работает автоматически, его придется форматировать самому и в итоговом отчете в шаге не аттачатся аргументы метода, как это происходило автоматически с `@allure.step`

Во время изучения кода репозитория allure-pytest мы наткнулись на хуки:

```
class AllureUserHooks(object):
    ..........

    @hookspec
    def start_step(self, uuid, title, params):
        """ step """

    @hookspec
    def stop_step(self, uuid, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        """ step """
```

У нас возник вопрос, есть ли способ создания обертки на основе этого хука внутри allure_commons? Что-то врорде:

```
@allure_commons.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def stop_step():
    take_screen()
    yield
```

Мы пытались запустить код выше, но, очевидно, он не работает как мы предполагали.

Я буду благодарен за любой совет или помощь.

P.S.
Такие вопросы наверняка были, но проведя поиск, я не нашел идентичного связанного с python (нашел только относительно Java), к тому же мы частично приблизились к решению.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для всех кто будет интересоваться, как выполнить задачу, я оставлю тут три решения, к которым пришел я.
Они представляют собой 3 (но в сущности 2) разных подхода, которые позволяют выполнить скриншоты на каждый шаг. А в случае с решением №3 - любые действия на каждый шаг.

## Решение №1: отдельный декоратор

Самым первым решением, которое позволило выполнить задачу со скриншотами, был следующий декоратор:

```
import allure
import wrapt


@wrapt.decorator(enabled=config.screen_each_step)
def attach_screenshot_if_configured(wrapped, instance, args, kwargs):
    method_result = wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
    _self = args[0]
    allure.attach(_self.driver.get_screenshot_as_png(), "step screenshot", allure.attachment_type.PNG)
    return method_result
```

И соответственно методы allure шагов с ним выглядели следующим образом:

```
@allure.step('I login to application by user {user_name}')
@attach_screenshot_if_configured
def login(self, user_name: str) -> None:
    ...
```

Его суть в том что как объект он содержит аргументы декорируемой функции, которые принимает `@allure.step` и шаг корректно формировался со всеми параметрами. Этого получилось добиться с помощью `@wrapt`.

Очевидные минусы - внутри декоратора необходим доступ к драйверу, что мы сделали через args[0], т.к. в нашем случае всем шаги - методы классов страниц (по паттерну PageObject), каждая из которых содержит ссылку на драйвер (self.driver).

## Решение №2: замена декоратора @allure.step

За это решение хочу поблагодарить @dmgant из чата Gitter allure-framework/allure-core который очень сильно помог подсказав основное направление.

```
import sys

from allure_commons.utils import func_parameters, represent
from allure_commons._allure import StepContext


def allure_step(step_title: str) -> Callable:
    def decorator(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            f_args = list(map(lambda x: represent(x), args))
            f_params = func_parameters(func, *args, **kwargs)

            title = step_title.format(*f_args, **f_params)
            step_obj = StepContext(title, f_params)
            # Enter context manager manually.
            step_obj.__enter__()
            try:
                # Execute original function.
                # conftest.before_allure_step()  # any action you want before step
                val = func(*args, **kwargs)
                # conftest.after_allure_step()   # any action you want after step
            finally:
                # Exit context manager manually.
                step_obj.__exit__(*sys.exc_info())
            return val
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Методы шагов выглядели следующим образом:

```
@allure_step('I login to application by user {user_name}')
def login(self, user_name: str) -> None:
    ...
```

Идея этого решения состоит в мануальном определении объекта шага и контроля точек входа\выхода в ручную. Аргументы декорируемой функции собираются и подставляются тем же способом, как это происходит в коде библиотеки `allure`.

Также в этом решении мы вынесли все действия до шага и после шага в условные "хуки" которые в моем случае лежат в файле `conftest` (в моем примере эти строки закомментированы и подписаны).

Минус у данного решения для нас был только один, этот декоратор, очевидно, невозможно использовать как context manager, что нам было нужно в том числе.
Однако все остальные поставленные задачи решение выполняет отлично.

## Решение №3: создание кастомного объекта выступающего в роли contextmanager и декоратора.

Это решение стало финальным:

```
from allure_commons.utils import func_parameters, represent
from allure_commons._allure import StepContext
from functools import wraps


def allure_step(title):
    if callable(title):
        return CustomStepContext(title.__name__, {})(title)
    else:
        return CustomStepContext(title, {})


class CustomStepContext(StepContext):

    def __enter__(self):
        super().__enter__()
        # conftest.before_allure_step()  # any action you want before "with allure_step"

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        # conftest.after_allure_step()   # any action you want after  "with allure_step
        super().__exit__(exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb)

    def __call__(self, func):
        @wraps(func)
        def impl(*args, **kwargs):
            f_args = list(map(lambda x: represent(x), args))
            f_params = func_parameters(func, *args, **kwargs)
            with StepContext(self.title.format(*f_args, **f_params), f_params):
                # conftest.before_allure_step()  # any action you want before step
                step_result =  func(*args, **kwargs)
                # conftest.after_allure_step()   # any action you want after step
                return step_result
        return impl
```

Методы шагов выглядели так же, как и в решении 2.

Идея решения такдже подсмотрена в коде библиотеки `allure`, а сам объект унаследован от аналогичного внутри библиотеки.
Разница только в том что это позволяет а) использовать эту замену и как context manager и как декоратор; б) это решение позволяет осуществлять любые действия перед шагом и после шага, которые в отчете будут частью этого шага.

P.S. Если в ответе не хватает каких-либо деталей, прошу указать на это, они обязательно будут добавлены.